# Which residue classes sit in the index two subgroups of the quotient of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ by $\langle\overline3\rangle$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, quotient-group

> Which residue classes of $\Bbb Z$ sit in the index two subgroups of the quotient of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ by $\langle\overline3\rangle$?

Let $\Bbb Z_2$ be the ring of 2 adic integers

Let $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Z_2$ by the obvious inclusion

Let $\langle3\rangle=\{3^i:i\in\Bbb Z\}$

Let $\langle\overline3\rangle$ be the closure of $\langle3\rangle$ under the 2-adic metric.

Then I'm informed unless I misunderstand [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480396/how-can-i-metrize-bbb-z-2-langle3-rangle?noredirect=1#comment7156243_3480396) that $\langle\overline3\rangle$ is an index two subgroup of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$.

Let $X\subseteq \{\{a,b\}:\forall y\in\Bbb Z,ay+b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times/\langle\overline3\rangle\}$ be some subset of the set of ordered pairs $a,b$ such that the residue classes $x\equiv b\pmod a$ cover the odd numbers $\Bbb 2\Bbb Z-1$.

Which residue classes of $\Bbb Z$ sit in each of the two cosets $X$ and $\not X$?  Or if they can't be defined by residue classes, which integers defined by some other means.

Comment: How about $3$ and $5$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton I increased the question's precision in light of your comment.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I don't need a full answer, just a simple way to partition $\Bbb Z$ would be plenty for me.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to partition $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ into $2$ classes, rather than $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: I’m not sure your question is well defined, yet. The ambient set $X$ is living in is all of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (forgetting order?). Are you asking which sets of the form $a\mathbb{Z}+b$ sit entirely within $\overline{\langle3\rangle}$ or its other coset?

Comment: @SantanaAfton yes that's precisely what I meant to ask.

Comment: @Malkoun That would be fine. I only restricted to $\Bbb Z$ because I feared elements of $\Bbb Z_2\setminus\Bbb Z$ might be more difficult to define.

Comment: Can you answer this question for $b=0$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton I am way slow at this stuff - hence asking here. The thing is, I have here a large set of residue classes and I want to compare them to the answer to this question.  I also have two or three bijections and an isometry which act on $\Bbb Z_2$ and again I want to determine which of these are closed to $X,\not X$, which alternate between the two cosets, and to understand whether the interplay with these cosets is of use to me.  But as for picking out all of the actual values of $X$, this is beyond me.

Comment: @SantanaAfton As for $b=0$, I have deliberately defined the question such that there are multiple subsets $X$ which form covers - I seek any one of them. I'm not sure if that's what you're getting at with your question.  I did that because there is not necessarily one canonical set of residue classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $a\ge 3$, $$(1+2^a(1+2b))^2 \equiv 1+2^{a+1}(1+2b)+2^{2a}(1+2b)^2\equiv 1+2^{a+1}\bmod 2^{a+2}$$ thus by induction on $a$ there is a power of $1+8$ which is equal to $1+8x \bmod 2^a $, ie. $(1+8)^{\Bbb{Z}}$ is dense in $1+8 \Bbb{Z}_2$.

The closure of $(1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}}$ is $(1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$, it contains $(1+2)^{2\Bbb{Z}_2}=(1+8)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}=1+8 \Bbb{Z}_2$.

Whence $\Bbb{Z}_2^\times / (1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$  is a quotient of  $\Bbb{Z}_2^\times/(1+8\Bbb{Z}_2) = \Bbb{Z/8Z}^\times$ and we obtain

$$\Bbb{Z}_2^\times =  (1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}\cup 5(1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$$

If $n \equiv 1$ or $3\bmod 8$ then $n\in (1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$, if $n\equiv 5$ or $7\bmod 8$ then $n\in 5(1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$.

Comment: Can you write a few words on how this answers OPs question? In particular there was some clarification in the comments.

Comment: $(1+2)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$ is the completion (for the $2$-adic metric) of the subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_2^\times$ generated by $3$, what the OP noted $\overline{\langle 3\rangle}$. You comments suggest you don't know what is the $2$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_2$, the completion (limits of Cauchy sequences) of $\Bbb{Z}$ for the "absolute value" $|2^k b|_2 =2^{-k}$ if $2\nmid b$

Comment: Much obliged, thank-you @reuns . If this interprets Jyrki's comment of yesterday then it is certainly what I'm looking for. If I have misinterpreted his comment of yesterday in any way then it is the question which I should adjust rather than for your answer to be adjusted to fit my question.

Comment: Ah, so you’re saying that if you’re even then you don’t live in the group, if you’re 1 or 3 mod 8 then you’re in the subgroup, if you’re 5 or 7 mod 8 you live in its coset, and that covers everyone.

Comment: For all $n\equiv 1$ or $3\bmod 8$ there is a sequence $(c_j)\in \{0,1\}$ such that $\forall J, (1+2)^{\sum_{j\le J} c_j 2^j} \equiv n\bmod 2^J$ ie. $\lim_{J\to \infty} (1+2)^{\sum_{j\le J} c_j 2^j}=n$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, the limit of the LHS is naturally written $(1+2)^c$ where $c=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j 2^j\in \Bbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @reuns, please could you provide more detail as to why the first formula implies that $(1+8)^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $1 + 8\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: By induction on $a$ there is a power of $9$ which is equal to $1+8x\bmod 2^a$ @Malkoun